# Is it always true that $Mx = 0 \text{ iff } M^TMx = 0\;?$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it always true that for $m$ by $n$  real valued matrix $M$ with $m < n$ and real valued vector $x$,

$$Mx = 0 \text{ iff } M^TMx = 0\;?$$

The implication one way is obvious but is the other way also always true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you know that for any vector $y$, $y^Ty=0$ iff $y=0$. Also, you need that $(MN)^T=N^TM^T$ for compatible matrices $M,N$.

Then: If $M^TMx=0$, let $y=Mx$ and we see:$$y^Ty=(Mx)^T(Mx)=x^TM^TMx=x^T(M^TMx)=0.$$ So $y=Mx=0$.

Answer (score 1):

So the question is-

> Prove that- $\mathcal{N}(M) = \mathcal{N}(M^TM)$ where $M \in \mathbb{F}^{m\times n} (m<n)$.

### Proving: $\mathcal{N}(M) \subseteq \mathcal{N}(M^TM)$

$x\in \mathcal{N}(M) \implies Mx=\theta_m$

So, $M^T \theta_m=\theta_n\implies M^T Mx = \theta_n$

So, $x\in \mathcal{N}(M^TM)$ which implies that $\mathcal{N}(M) \subseteq \mathcal{N}(M^TM)$. $\dots(1)$

### Proving: $\mathcal{N}(M^T M) \subseteq \mathcal{N}(M)$

$x\in \mathcal{N}(M^T M) \implies M^T Mx=\theta_n$

So, $x^T M^T M x=0\implies (Mx)^T Mx = \theta_m \implies\left\|Mx\right\|_2^2=0 \implies Mx = \theta_m$

So, $x\in \mathcal{N}(M)$ which implies that $\mathcal{N}(M^TM) \subseteq \mathcal{N}(M)$. $\dots(2)$

**From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we can conclude that- $\mathcal{N}(M) = \mathcal{N}(M^TM)$.**